# Is Safari on iPad and iPhone identical?

Tags: ios, development, mobile-safari

I have an iPad for testing websites I develop but am wondering, does this completely cover me for the same version iOS on a mobile?

And I don't mean roughly, would it be exactly the same code base for Safari regardless of the device (so long as the operating systems were the same)?

Answer (score 1):

The binary might be the same, but the code contains conditionals so that some parts works differently on the iPad compared to the iPhone. Just check out the user interface - they are definitely not identical.

Besides, there's obvious differences in for example screen size, resolution, CPU speed and RAM.

If you haven't got an iPhone to test with you could download Xcode from Apple and use the iPhone simulator to test your web sites with.

Comment: Do you know if the difference will affect page rendering and Javascript at all?

Comment: Well, there’s obvious differences in screen size, resolution, CPU speed and RAM... but you wouldn’t expect Javascript to be interpreted differently for example.

Answer (score 1):

It does change rendering. The ipad has much more screen space. If you want to support mobile devices then you should test on various screen sizes. 
The Javascript should run the same but how the elements are laid out can very.

Comment: I'm not concerned about screen sizes, that is straightforward to test. The issue is how things behave, and as I found out today iOS Safari has some very strange quirks that require hacky fixes to make things work.